# CreateTableRequest / KeySchemaElement / Attributes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

If I defined a class with these attributes

```
 [DynamoDBTable("UserPictures")]
  public class UserInfo
  {

    public UserInfo()
    {
      if (PictureAlbum == null)
        PictureAlbum = new Dictionary<string, PictureInfo>();
    }

    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [DynamoDBRangeKey]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, PictureInfo> PictureAlbum { get; set; }

  }
```

Why does CreateTableRequest require 1) tablename, and 2)KeySchemaElement? Can't those be determined by reading the attributes on the class?

Comment: By reading the attributes of the class, it can't determine the key attribues. It requires the DynamoDBHashKey and DynamoDBRangeKey to identify the same. These are mandatory fields for the Dynamodb table.

Comment: Both of those fields are marked with attributes ....

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB manages the data based on the `partition key`. Partition key is used to identify the item in the database. An item can't be **created/updated/queried** without partition key. Only scan can be performed without partition key.

The main difference between partition (sort key if available) and other non-key attributes is that partition key is mandatory. All other attributes are not mandatory.

[How partition key works](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html)

Also, while creating the table, DynamoDB made partition key and sort key (if available) attributes has mandatory. It doesn't allow to define any non-key attributes. Event if you try to define the non-key attributes while creating the table, DynamoDB will throws exception as it is a **NoSQL database and Schema less**.

**There are two types of attributes:-**

1) Key attributes:- 
**Partition Key** - Mandatory to be defined while creating the table. All the item must have value for this attribute

**Sort key** - Table may or may not contain this attribute based on the design. If it is defined, then all the items should have value for this attribute

2) Non-Key attributes - Optional attributes. An item may or may not contain non-key attribute

When table is created, it has to know the key attributes. So that it can manage the data and distribute it to different partitions based on the partition key. The whole database is managed based on the partition key. That's why it has to be unique and the value should be scattered to get good performance. In other words, the key should be designed in such a way that the data is scattered across multiple partitions.